# Tweetdeck and Tweeten: Streaming of new tweets broken?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

For several days now my Tweetdeck and Tweeten have changed their behavior regarding the streaming of new tweets.

So far, new tweets showed up in each column on top and older tweets were pushed down. Hence, I could always see the newest tweets on top of each column which made for a pleasant experience.

However, now behavior has become unpredictable: When new tweets are incoming then the visible position in each column jumps to an unpredictable vertical position, meaning, I cannot see the newest tweets anymore. It is almost as if I scrolled down to older tweets in each column. I have to click on the column header to move all the way back up to the top but after a short time with new incoming tweets, the same routine repeats itself.

Has there been a significant change to how Tweetdeck and Tweeten interact with the core Twitter engine? I experience the same issues with different browsers and Tweetdeck and also with the Windows Store App Tweeten as well. Just a week ago everything worked fine.

Anyone else experiencing this?